# In Zig, on Windows, how to detect if running as Administrator

Tags: windows, symlink, zig

I'd like to determine if my Zig test code is running via "Run As Administrator ..." (or its equivalent) under Windows.  Is a check for this or something like it exposed via the Zig standard library?

I'm actually interested in determining if my code can create symlinks on Windows, and those seem to require Admin privileges in Windows.  So I'm also curious if there are any caveats around using an is-administrator check with respect to symlinks.

Comment: There is [std.os.windows.CreateSymbolicLink](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:os.windows.CreateSymbolicLink) which fails with an `AccessDenied` error; would this work for you?

Comment: In my case it wouldn't because I'm trying to determine if the `AccessDenied` error from CreateSymbolicLink is "expected" (because of missing Admin privs) or is "unexpected" (if its returned with Admin privs active).

Comment: @P.T. there isn’t really a difference, since you can give those privileges to any user account. What you should do instead is request those privileges in advance. Unfortunately the process for doing that is a bit convoluted in windows, depending on where exactly you’re going to deploy your application and how exactly your application works there are different ways to go about doing that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/user-account-control